# Get data from exteral source into OKS Survey's forms

Tags: survey, odk

Is there a way to add external data to the ODK Survey form, like the "pulldata" method in the Collect Forms? I know about queries but this are used to populate a multiple choice prompt with values.

I need a tool that will get data either form outside the form (from a cvs for example) or from an array or something inside the xlsx form, and set that value to a prompt inside the form. Any ides?

Thank you!